# C# 6 safe navigation not working in VS2015 preview

Tags: c#, roslyn, c#-6.0

I have the following property in my code

```
public float X {
    get {
        if (parent != null)
            return parent.X + position.X;
        return position.X;
    }
    set { position.X = value; }
}
```

I was hoping to convert the getter into the form of

```
    get {
        return parent?.X + position.X;
    }
```

But I get the following error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'float?' to 'float'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Am I doing something wrong or is it not available right now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of `parent?.X` is `float?`, which you're adding to a `float` - resulting in another `float?`. That can't be implicitly converted to `float`.

While Yuval's answer should work, I would personally use something like:

```
get
{
    return (parent?.X ?? 0f) + position.X;
}
```

or

```
get
{
    return (parent?.X).GetValueOrDefault() + position.X;
}
```

I'm not sure of your design, mind you - the fact that you add something in the getter but not in the setter is odd. It means that:

```
foo.X = foo.X;
```

... will not be a no-op if `parent` is non-null with a non-zero `X` value.

Comment: That makes sense. For some reasons, it didn't occur to me that value types are non-nullable and that the examples I saw on the elvis operator work with reference types.

Answer (score 0):

Using the null propagation operator in your case will attempt to return `null` if parent is `null`.
This would only be possible if `float` is nullable, hence `float?`.

You can instead to the following:

```
get 
{
   return parent?.X + position.X ?? position.x;
}
```

This will use the null-coalescing operator as a fallback if `parent` returns null.